# I want to put my if-else into switch case but the output does not show the correct result that it should be

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to put if-else into switch case, it works but the issue is that the result of the calculation is incorrect

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int unit, disc, total, discprice, caseof;
    int a = 99;

    cout << "Enter number of units sold: ";
    cin >> unit;

    if (unit > 10 && unit < 19) 
    {
        unit = '1';
    }

    if (unit > 20 && unit < 49) 
    {
        unit = '2';
    }
    if (unit > 50 && unit < 99)
    {
        unit = '3';
    }
    if (unit > 100) 
    {
        unit = '4';
    }
    else if (unit <= 10) 
    {
        cout << "Number of units sold" << endl;
        cout << "Total amount of units: RM" << total << endl;
    }
    switch (unit)
    {
    case '1':
        total = unit * a;
        disc = total * 0.3;
        discprice = total - disc;
        cout << "Number of units sold= " << unit << endl;
        cout << "Total amount of units: RM" << total << endl;
        cout << "Total amount after 30% discount is RM" << discprice << endl;
        break;

    case '2':
        total = unit * a;
        disc = total * 0.3;
        discprice = total - disc;
        cout << "Number of units sold= " << unit << endl;
        cout << "Total amount of units: RM" << total << endl;
        cout << "Total amount after 30% discount is RM" << discprice << endl;
        break;

    case '3':
        total = unit * a;
        disc = total * 0.4;
        discprice = total - disc;
        cout << "Number of units sold= " << unit << endl;
        cout << "Total amount of units: RM" << total << endl;
        cout << "Total amount after 40% discount is RM" << discprice << endl;
        break;

    case '4':
        total = unit * 2;
        disc = total * 0.5;
        discprice = total - disc;
        cout << "Number of units sold= " << unit << endl;
        cout << "Total amount of units: RM" << total << endl;
        cout << "Total amount after 50% discount is RM" << discprice << endl;
        break;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

The expected output should calculated and show the discounted price of the products. Ex: When I put 15 as unit in the program the number of units sold should appear as 15 and use case 1 to multiply 0.2 and show the discounted price. Instead it shows 49 in Number of units sold.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost just a typo problem, but you defined `unit` to be `int`, yet you actually are assigning to it character literals.  Instead of:

```
int unit = '1';
```

you should use:

```
int unit = 1;
```

As an alternative, which I do not recommend, you could cope with the character assignments by converting back to the original integer numbers, e.g.

```
switch (unit - '0')
{
    case 1:
        // case 1
        // etc., using unit - '0' everywhere for the actual unit integer value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First avoid code repetition: 
This:

```
total = unit * 2;
        disc = total * 0.5;
        discprice = total - disc;
        cout << "Number of units sold= " << unit << endl;
        cout << "Total amount of units: RM" << total << endl;
        cout << "Total amount after 50% discount is RM" << discprice << endl;
```

can become something like this

```
total(units, 2, 0.5);
```

somewhere else you can use:
    total(units, a, 0.3);

Declare a function like :

```
void compute_total(int units, int correction, float disc_ratio ){
...
}
```

That cleans your code a lot.
Second, c types matter. int unit has int size (at least two bytes), and in some architectures that might not be what you expect giving it char literal '1' (normally 1 byte).

Another type conversion occurs when you do total *0.3, it should return 445.5, but it round to 445
total = 15 * 99
total * 0.3,

Last, your if chain is not working as expected also. This is the real problem, 49  is ascii for '1', as you reassign unit, you are actually giving 49 value to it.

If you chain your ifs with elses as: 
if() else if()
still won't solve it.
**I advise you to not reassign units variable, create a new one, say "char pricing_strategy".**

Notice you can manually do 
case 1: case 2: ... case 10: code break; case 11: ... ; case 100: ... break; default: //>100 break;
And avoid if chain, it is not really worth it, and pretty hard on yourself later if you have to change for some reason.